# Azure AD Mobile Authentication using Common Tenant

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, azure-active-directory

I'm writing a Xamarin app, and I'd like to give my users the ability to sign in with Azure AD from any tenant.  In the world of web apps, you can do that using the common tenant; however, for some reason it seems like that's a problem for mobile apps.

Based on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#adal, my client code looks like this:

```
private async Task AadAuthenticateAsync()
{
    const string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
    const string resourceId = "<My Resource ID>";
    const string clientId = "<My Client ID>";
    string redirectUri = $"{AppSettings.ServerUri}/.auth/login/done";
    try
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(this));
        var payload = new JObject { ["access_token"] = authResult.AccessToken };
        _user = await _client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, payload);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.SetMessage(ex.Message);
        builder.SetTitle("You must log in. Login Required");
        builder.Create().Show();
    }
}
```

However, when I sign in using this flow, the `_client.LoginAsync` step throws an exception, saying "You do not have permission to view this directory or page".

My web app is already configured to be multi-tenant, so I would have expected this flow to work as expected.  Am I missing something, or is there another way to do this, given that it should be a fairly common use case?

**UPDATE**

When I first set this system up, I used a tenant without any users as my realm.  All other tenants, including the tenant containing my own users, will be signing in using the common tenant.  Following Saca's suggestion, I set up a user in `mytenant.onmicrosoft.com`, and signing in as that user works without a hitch: both for the authority `login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com` and `login.microsoftonline.com/common`.  However, any user from any other tenant blows up with the same exception.  In other words, although I've set the web app up as a multi-tenant app, mobile authentication seems not to accept the multi-tenant use case.

The request URL that gets invoked by `_client.LoginAsync()` is `/.auth/login/aad`.

**UPDATE 2** At Saca's request, here is the stack trace:

at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+d__18.MoveNext () [0x0022f] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+d__1d.MoveNext () [0x0010d] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+d__4.MoveNext () [0x00118] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+d__0.MoveNext () [0x0008d] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceAuthentication+d__0.MoveNext () [0x0006d] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Oceanus.Droid.MainActivity+d__9.MoveNext () [0x001cd] in C:\Users\Rob Lyndon\Documents\GitHub\Oceanus\Oceanus\Oceanus.Droid\MainActivity.cs:103

Comment: What's the URL and other details for the request that's coming back with this error? (You can use Fiddler to find this out). Does this work for single-tenant with the https://login.microsoftonline.com/<youtenant.onmicrosoft.com> endpoint? I suspect there's something more fundamentally broken here, not related to multi-tenancy.

Comment: Side note, you should use https://login.microsoftonline.com

Comment: It turns out I've already made that change in my code (edited the question accordingly).  I'll give Fiddler a go and come back to you.

Comment: The URL, as expected, is `/.auth/login/aad`.  I'm trying to login with my tenant, but it's difficult to log out from the current tenant.

Comment: And it works without a hitch when I use single-tenant for login.microsoftonline.com/<mytenant.onmicrosoft.com>.

Comment: And also login.microsoftonline.com/common.  I've updated the question.

Comment: How did you configure your Mobile App in Azure? Express or Advanced? I'm still poking around but at first glance it seems that Mobile App services doesn't support multi-tenant given that it asks for an Issuer URL which in the multi-tenant case varies depending on which tenant is signing in.

Comment: Advanced.  That could make sense, but it would be a shame.  I imagine it can be done manually.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace for your error?

Comment: Done -- added in the question.